# Is there a known bug with memory managing or paging file sizes between Python's multiprocessor and recent Win 10 updates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windows, multiprocessing

I have a script in Python that uses the multiprocessor library and it was running fine.  Then the next day I decided to run it again but it gave memory errors, and page file is too small errors.  The only thing I can think of that changed was my hard disk space and updates to windows.
I thought it might have to do with a windows update conflict so I uninstalled Python 3.8.3 and upgraded to 3.9 and updated all dependent packages as well as the C++ distributable.
The one thing I tried was reducing the number of workers by another 6 workers.  It worked but obviously was slower.  I normally operate with -4 workers from total, and it posed no issues.  I even tried running with all other applications turned off and network disabled, still the problem persists with -4 cores.  Works with -10 cores though.  It seems like something happened that requires the script to use more memory which explains why reducing the number of process instances works.  But is this a bug that's causing this?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas\_libs\interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
  File "pandas\_libs\missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    exec(code, run_globals)
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\david\Documents\GitHub\nimbleheart\Modules\STRATTEST_MULTITRIAL_MASTER.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\david\Documents\GitHub\nimbleheart\Modules\STRATTEST_MULTITRIAL_MASTER.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .conversion import OutOfBoundsTimedelta, localize_pydatetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 58, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing
    from pandas.core.api import (
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\offsets.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays.interval import IntervalArray
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\interval.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 57, in <module>
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx", line 47, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps
    from pandas.core.indexes.base import ensure_index
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pandas.core.aggregation import (
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes import concat as _concat
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\concat.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import FrameOrSeriesUnion, Series
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing fields: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 68, in <module>

The above exception was the di
```

Answer (score 0):

None that I am aware of. There has been some issues with Panda 1.0.3 (when I last used it) on Windows which broke depending on the DLL locations/fallbacks etc. I would try installing the latest [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and see if that works (you already did, just re-iterating the steps I took). Could be the Windows update removed/updated something...

You might also try to copy concrt140.dll and msvcp140.dll from C:\Windows\System32 to pandas_libs\windows folder if you already have the latest installed.

Last resort would be to revert Pandas and/or Python to a known working copy (for me it was 1.0.1 and python 3.7)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: Hi again.  Just to update you, I fixed it.  Switching to an older version of numpy and pandas did it for me.  I must've forgotten that I updated numpy/pandas which is probably what caused the problem in the first place.  Thank you for your help!!!!!!